# Is there possible isentropic phase transition?

Tags: entropy, phase-transition, topological-phase

Suppose we have a complex system changing in state but without order parameter jump. Is there possible that during this change particular dynamic of system chsnges enough to name this phase change, but without entropy growth? Any example? Topological PT? Subtle changes in liquid crystals? Some subtle collective quantum phenomena?

I ASKING ABOUT CONSTANT ENTROPY. STOP ANSWERING ABOUT CONTINUOUS ENTROPY. **ISENTROPIC** means constant entropy

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process

Comment: Second order phase transitions.

Comment: In second order PT entropy is continuous, not constant. Could you give particular example?

Comment: Entropy staying strictly constant sounds like a too restrictive thing to think about, at least in the context of statistical mechanics. Generally the entropy changes smoothly as a function of your tuning parameter. Maybe relaxing it to "without entropy having a sudden jump" would make more sense; and in that case, it is a second-order phase transition.

Comment: This is exactly the reason I am asking. Is it even possible?

Comment: ferromagnetic - paramagnetic transition at the Curie temperature occurs with continuous (no jump) entropy, and is called 2nd order in the Ehrenfest classification. Th entropy is "constant" around the $T_C$ Curie temperature because $S(T_C^{0-})=S(T_C^{0+})$

Comment: I am asking about constant entropy. Not continuous

Comment: This is essentially asking can an adiabat and the coexistence line for second order phase transition intersect. I don’t see an obvious reason why not

Comment: Thinking about this more carefully, since every state lies on some curve of constant entropy, the only ways this can fail to be possible are if there is an entropy discontinuity, i.e. it is a discontinuous phase transition, or if the phase boundry is itself the curve of constant entropy, which I am pretty sure is not true in general and should be easy to find a counter example for

Answer (score 2):

If you are just asking about a phase transition where the entropy stays exactly the same, any [*quantum* phase transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_transition) will have that property quite trivially, because all QPTs happen at $T=0$ by definition, giving entropy density $s=0$ (as long as you don't have extensive residual entropy) as a constant.

For thermal phase transitions (i.e. phase transitions that happen at $T>0$), as @By_Symmetry points out in the comment, it is also possible, since an isentropic process can totally cross a second-order phase transition. For example, even with the standard water-vapor transition, since isentropic curves must cover the entire phase diagram and phase boundaries are generic curves, there should be isentropic curves that go through a phase transition, regardless of the degree (continuous or discontinuous) of the phase transition.